# Skip iteration of loop under one condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, so thank you in advance for your patience. I created a sub that checks if each value in col F is found in col A on another sheet. If the value isn't on the other sheet, it highlights the cell in yellow. There's one issue: if the cell contains "XXX", I want the loop to not highlight the cell and move on to the next one. I've found many similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817051/move-onto-next-iteration-of-loop-in-excel-vba), and many that warn against using `GoTo` as a workaround. Here is my code:

```
'PURPOSE: Finds and highlight all values in Routing List Adapters that are not found in Summary Adapters
Sub SummaryCheck_1()
Dim RoutingList As Worksheet
Dim Summary As Worksheet
Dim RoutingList_Adapters1 As Range
Dim Summary_Adapters As Range
Dim Adapter As Range
Dim AdapterValue As String
Dim Match As Range

'Sets worksheets
Set RoutingList = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Routing List")
Set Summary = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")


'Sets Routing List Adapter Fitting (1) range and Summary Adapter range
'Corresponds to Adapter Fitting (1) column
Set RoutingList_Adapters1 = RoutingList.Range(("F3"), RoutingList.Range("F3").End(xlDown))
Set Summary_Adapters = Summary.Range(("A4"), Summary.Range("A4").End(xlDown))

'Finds and highlights all Routing List Adapter Fittings (1) not found in Summary Adapters
For Each Adapter In RoutingList_Adapters1
    AdapterValue = Adapter.Value
    Set Match = Summary_Adapters.Find(What:=AdapterValue, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Match Is Nothing Then
        Adapter.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    ElseIf Not Match Is Nothing Then
        Match.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    ElseIf InStr(AdapterValue, "XXX") > 0 Then
        'Here is where I want to insert code to skip cells containing "XXX"
    End If
Next Adapter
End Sub
```

Let me know if this sub needs more explantation. I tried one workaround, which is resetting the interior color to `RGB(255,255,255)` for all cells containing "XXX," but unfortunately many of the sheet rows are already color-coded, so I need to just skip cells containing "XXX" altogether. Thank you in advance for any insights on how to skip the loop iteration for this single condition!

Answer (score 0):

There are better methods, a quick one can be
`Match.Interior.Color = Match.Interior.Color`

Comment: I added ```Match.Interior.Color = Match.Interior.Color``` right in the place in the code where I wrote ```'Here is where I want to insert code to skip cells containing "XXX"```, but it still made the XXX columns yellow. Do I need to change where I have the ```Match.Interior.Color = Match.Interior.Color``` code? Perhaps in an ElseIf isn't the right spot?

Answer (score 0):

Added `And InStr(AdapterValue, "XXX") = 0`, changed the code to this:

```
'PURPOSE: Finds and highlight all values in Routing List Adapters that are not found in Summary Adapters
Sub SummaryCheck_1()
Dim RoutingList As Worksheet
Dim Summary As Worksheet
Dim RoutingList_Adapters1 As Range
Dim Summary_Adapters As Range
Dim Adapter As Range
Dim AdapterValue As String
Dim Match As Range

'Sets worksheets
Set RoutingList = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Routing List")
Set Summary = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")


'Sets Routing List Adapter Fitting (1) range and Summary Adapter range
'Corresponds to Adapter Fitting (1) column
Set RoutingList_Adapters1 = RoutingList.Range(("F3"), RoutingList.Range("F3").End(xlDown))
Set Summary_Adapters = Summary.Range(("A4"), Summary.Range("A4").End(xlDown))

'Finds and highlights all Routing List Adapter Fittings (1) not found in Summary Adapters
For Each Adapter In RoutingList_Adapters1
    AdapterValue = Adapter.Value
    Set Match = Summary_Adapters.Find(What:=AdapterValue, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Match Is Nothing And InStr(AdapterValue, "XXX") = 0 Then
        Adapter.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    ElseIf Not Match Is Nothing Then
        Match.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If
Next Adapter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to skip the XXX ones altogether?

```vb
    If InStr(AdapterValue, "XXX") = 0 Then
        If Match Is Nothing Then
            Adapter.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Else
            Adapter.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
    End If
```

I assumed you want to colour in green the cells where you found a match, maybe I misunderstood your code.